# Referencing image in HTML in Confluence

Tags: javascript, html, confluence

So what I'm doing is I have to put a picture in a confluence page and when I click that I have to show a pop-up of text, and it's only possible in Confluence if I use an html,  but I don't know where to store the images that I will be using for this (), where should I store the image so I can reference it from my html.

Answer (score 2):

I already did this, so in case someone would ask the same question, when you use an html macro in your Confluence page, it will serve as the whole page's content so when you place some attachments in it it won't appear if you save what you've edited.

1. Insert your image attachment by clicking on Insert->Attachment
2. Clicked on the attached image and copy the url (/confluence/......./example.jpg)
3. reference it it your html in your img tag